# Does this function change the size of the array?

Tags: c

So I am starting to learn C. I am learning from the classic K&R book. In the book they have the following function:

```
/*squeeze: delete all c from s */
void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

My question is this: does squeeze() actually change the number of chars in s[]?
It seems that all it does is "cut off" the rest of the string by adding the null character. Do other values exist past the '\0' in the array?

Comment: there are other values, but they aren't allocated for `s`.

Comment: **Arrays NEVER change size!** Not even VLAs! Memory areas allocated with `malloc()` can change size.

Comment: Note that `s` in your code is not an array: it is a pointer.

Comment: @pmg It looks like an array to me. `char s[]`?

Comment: @Paulpro: see 6.7.6.3.7 in the Standard: [Function declarators (including prototypes)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string in c is just an array of characters with a null terminator, `\0`, signifying the end. Characters can still exist after the null terminator, but any functions using c strings, ie. `printf` or `strcpy` will use the null terminator to mark the end, so it will effectively be treated as if there were nothing after the `\0`.

Answer (score 2):

No `squeeze()` does not change the number of characters in the string, it will look for the character passed as the second argument in the string passed as the first argument and remove it and then terminate the string with `\0`.

After that character the memory will still have values allocated to it but they will be ignored by string related functions in C.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is declared as a character array

```
char s[]
```

Though it is adjusted to pointer of type `char *` nevertheles it is supposed  that the function deals with a character array that stores a string.

String is a sequence of characters terminated by zero character.

The function removes characters equal to the character specified by parameter c from the string. It simply overwrites these characters and moves the terminating zero left. The size of the array is not changed.

Thus the function changes the length of the string stored in the array not the size of the array itself.

To determine the length of a string you should use standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>`

Consider this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[100] = "Hello World";

    printf( "The size of the array is %zu\n", sizeof( s ) );
    printf( "The length of the string in the array is %zu\n", strlen( s ) );
}
```

If I entered the program correctly without a typo then its output will be

```
The size of the array is 100
The length of the string in the array is 11
```